# Django form queryset: excluding existing records

Tags: django, forms, django-queryset

In Django, I have the following models: one is the branch shop, another is the basic fruit, and the other is the fruit that is sold in each branch shop:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class BranchFruit(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit)
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('branch', 'fruit')
```

A form is provided for adding new fruits, and the queryset should exclude the fruits already available in THAT shop. I am thinking using the following:

Form:

```
class BranchFruitForm(modelForm):
    fruit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Fruit.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BranchFruitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        excludes = BranchFruit.objects.filter(branch=args)
        includes = Fruit.objects.filter(~Q([exc.fruit for exc in excludes]))
        self.fields['fruit'].queryset = includes
```

The views.py contains:

```
if request.method=='GET':
    branch = request.user.branch   # The branch shop the user belongs to
    return render(request, template, {'branchFruitForm':BranchFruitForm(branch)})
```

But the BranchFruitForm fails at the `excludes` statement with the following message:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Branch'
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
def __init__(self, branch, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BranchFruitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    branchFruits = BranchFruit.objects.filter(branch_id=branch.id)
    excludes = [fruit.fruit.id for fruit in branchFruits]
    self.fields['fruit'].queryset = Fruit.objects.all().exclude(id__in=excludes)
```

Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's expecting IDs not objects. Try building a list of ids and passing it in.

Comment: Additionally you can simply do self.fileds["fruits"].queryset = Fruit.objects. all().exclude (id__in, *listofids)

Answer (score 1):

in this line
    excludes = BranchFruit.objects.filter(branch=args)

try this 
    excludes = BranchFruit.objects.filter(branch_id__in=[args])